# Rate Limiting the queue receiver in Azures Service Bus Queues

Tags: node.js, message-queue, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, rate-limiting

I have to apply a **rate limit of 5 messages per sec** on my queue receiver, this rate limit should work even if the receiver is available on multiple deployed pods. Is there a way to apply rate limit on queue receiver in Azure Service Bus Queues?

I want to apply similar implementation that is provided by **Bull Queue** in **Azure Service Bus Queues**, i.e.

```
// Limit queue to max 5 jobs per 1 second.
const myRateLimitedQueue = new Queue('rateLimited', {
  limiter: {
    max: 5,
    duration: 1000
  }
});
```

Is there a workaround to do the same thing in Azure Service Bus Queue.

I am using **@azure/service-bus** package in my **node js** project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Service Bus does not provide rate limiting.

You could raise a feature request with the product team by [opening an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues).